# How do I see the changelog for a debian/ubuntu deb package?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, package-management, deb

I'm running Ubuntu and I have a deb file installed. I've made deb packages before, so I know there is a debian changelog (debchange). Is there anyway to see the debian changelog for any package that I have installed? Assume I don't have access to the deb source file for this package, and I don't have the deb file available. I am able to install extra packages if needed.

Comment: to see changes for `apt-get` installed packages: `apt-get changelog <package>`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `apt-get` doesn't have such a command.

Comment: @gipi: `apt-get changelog apt | grep -C5 'apt-get changelog'` shows that this command is introduced in `apt (0.8.9ubuntu1) natty` (2010). You can get the source (it is open-source after all): run `apt-get source apt` and find `cmdline/apt-get.cc` file and look at `DoChangelog()` function (btw, look at `DoMoo()` function).

Comment: strange, I have the (debian) apt 0.9.12.1 and this command is not available.

Comment: I know the question is old, but it would be nice if you accept an answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Alternatively if the deb is also in the repository and you want to know older versions changelog, you can use `apt-get changelog package` to read all the changelog. For example for openssl:

```
apt-get changelog libssl1.0.0
```

Comment: This is definitely the relevant answer for 2016 in both Debian Jessie and Ubuntu :)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

`apt-listchanges` is a nice package to have around, but without having a deb file around your best bet most probably is to read the Debian changelog from */usr/share/doc/somepackage/changelog.Debian.gz*.

Create a shell function with:

```
function debchanglog () {
  zless "/usr/share/doc/$1/changelog.Debian.gz"
}
```

Comment: As the OP alluded to, `debchange` is actually an existing tool in **devscripts** used for *creating* changelog entries. So I'd strongly recommend choosing another name. Also, `$0` will probably not do what you're expecting. In my case, it will always execute `zless /usr/share/doc/bash/changelog.Debian.gz`. In your case, replace `bash` with the name of the shell or script you are executing it from.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on Janne Pikkarainen's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/174743/301799), here is an alias that can be used to read the changelog.Debian.gz for any given package:

```
alias changelog="xargs -I% -- zless /usr/share/doc/%/changelog.Debian.gz <<<"
```

It can be used like so:

```
changelog PACKAGE
```

Please note however that this is a terribly hackish solution and is not recommended under most circumstances. A function or standalone script is a much better solution.

Here is a function that reads all available changelogs for PACKAGE:

```
changelog(){
    if (( $# != 1 )); then
        echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} PACKAGE"
        return 1
    fi

    find -L "/usr/share/doc/$1" -type f -name 'changelog*.gz' -exec zless {} \; 2>/dev/null
}
```

Here is a function that prints a list of all available changelogs for PACKAGE and queries the user to select which one to read:

```
changelog(){
    if (( $# != 1 )); then
        echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} PACKAGE"
        return 1
    fi

    local changelog changelogs

    readarray -t changelogs < <(find -L "/usr/share/doc/$1" -type f -name 'changelog*.gz' 2>/dev/null)

    if (( ${#changelogs[@]} == 0 )); then
        return 0
    elif (( ${#changelogs[@]} == 1 )); then
        zless "${changelogs[0]}"
        return $?
    fi

    select changelog in "${changelogs[@]}" EXIT; do
        case $changelog in
            '')
                echo "ERROR: Invalid selection" >&2
                continue
                ;;
            EXIT)
                return 0
                ;;
            *)
                zless "$changelog"
                return $?
                ;;
        esac            
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04+, the modern version of `apt` can do this (as opposed to `apt-get`):

```
ubuntu18-04:~% apt changelog nginx
nginx (1.14.0-0ubuntu1.9) bionic-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: DNS Resolver issues
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-23017-1.patch: fixed off-by-one write in
      src/core/ngx_resolver.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-23017-2.patch: fixed off-by-one read in
      src/core/ngx_resolver.c.
    - CVE-2021-23017
...
```